# How to fix these errors arising due to server blocking web scraping?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am trying to get the text from a web page using the "*get_text*" function as described [here](https://github.com/weblyzard/inscriptis).

```
import urllib.request
from inscriptis import get_text

url = "http://www.informationscience.ch"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')

text = get_text(html)

print(text)
```

This works fine for this particular website, but when I try to scrape from another website, I get the 403 Error:

```
import urllib.request
from inscriptis import get_text

url = "https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/stocks/news/birla-group-enters-the-fray-to-acquire-idbi-federal-life/articleshow/64251332.cms"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')

text = get_text(html)

print(text)
```

This gives the following error in the line `html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')`:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

---

I tried to fix it by specifying a user agent as follows:

```
import urllib.request
from inscriptis import get_text

url = "https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/stocks/news/birla-group-enters-the-fray-to-acquire-idbi-federal-life/articleshow/64251332.cms"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).read().decode('utf-8')

text = get_text(html)

print(text)
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: urlopen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'
```

---

Since the error said `headers` is undefined for `urlopen`, I tried to specify the user agent with the `requests` module as follows:

```
from inscriptis import get_text
import requests
url = requests.get('https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/stocks/news/birla-group-enters-the-fray-to-acquire-idbi-federal-life/articleshow/64251332.cms', "lxml", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

print(get_text(url))
```

But this gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

How do I get this damn server to stop blocking my web crawls please?

Comment: all these error seem unrelated: First error being an resource access on the website, that is just forbidden to you to access server-sided; Second error is you using the wrong keyword to the function-api; Third error seems to be related to something burried deeper in your code, if you cannot give any more error context (You are not using an object 'Response' in teh code you posted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to process the body of the response, not the response object itself:

```
response = requests.get('https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/stocks/news/birla-group-enters-the-fray-to-acquire-idbi-federal-life/articleshow/64251332.cms', "lxml", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

print(get_text(response.text))
```

Comment: This gives the error `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'body'`.

Comment: Try `response.text`

Comment: @MartinEvans Ok, that works. But, it prints out all the text (even the text in other links in that page, other ads posted on the page, etc). I just wanted the text in the main article, which is only a fraction of the content that is being printed.

Comment: Ok, solved it. I used beautiful soup to find and extract the text body in the "Normal" class div.